# MDX : transform a SELECT into a WITH statement

Tags: ssas, mdx

I am stuck trying to convert an MDX query statement into a WITH statement. I would like to achieve this in order to reuse the calculated number in an other query.

Here is the query:

```
SELECT [Measures].[VPARCOURS Nombre] ON 0
FROM [BDD PBM]
where { [Dim misc].[CCAMs].[CCAM].MEMBERS - [Dim misc].[CCAMs].[CCAM].&[] }
```

and here is what I am trying to get:

```
with member Nombre as ...
select [Nombre],<I will add some other things here later>
```

Can you help me?

### EDIT

Thank you MoazRub for your answer; I will explain you the whole thing.
The original query is as follow:

```
with
MEMBER Nombre AS [Measures].[VPARCOURS Nombre]
MEMBER [Nombre total] AS 
nonempty(filter([Dim misc].[CCAMs].[Patient Id].members, [Dim misc].[CCAMs].currentmember.parent.membervalue <> "")
    ,[Measures].[VPARCOURS Nombre]
).count
MEMBER Pourcentage AS Nombre / [Nombre total] * 100

SELECT
{ Nombre, [Nombre total], Pourcentage } ON 0,
TopPercent(
    filter([Dim misc].[CCAMs].[CCAM].members, [Dim misc].[CCAMs].currentmember.membervalue <> "" ),
    80,
    [Measures].[VPARCOURS Nombre])
ON 1
FROM [BDD PBM]
where strtoset(@hospital_CCAM)
```

The point is the computing of the member [Nombre total] i.e. the total number of patients whose CCAM is not "". It is computed in the line beginning by 'nonempty'. In my cube, I have a degenerate dimension, [Dim misc], which contains a hierarchy, CCAMs, with inside it 2 levels : CCAM(a category, it is a string field, and patients can have a CCAM, or the empty CCAM, "" ), and PatientId, added here only to make this request work. This request works, but using PatientId expresselly is not very satisfying, because after all OLAP cubes have the summing function natively.
So I wanted to calculate the total number of patients whose CCAM is not "", and this request I put in my question seem better, but the only thing I would like is not to alter the other computations.

Answer (score 1):

What I understand is you want to merge both the queries.if that is so, then below is how you will do it.

with member Nombre as ...
SELECT {[Measures].[VPARCOURS Nombre],Measures.Nombre }
ON 0
FROM [BDD PBM]
where { [Dim misc].[CCAMs].[CCAM].MEMBERS - [Dim misc].[CCAMs].[CCAM].&[] }

Comment: I do not want to merge the two queries, just compute the member and reuse it in the second query. It's like a sub query in sql, inside an usual query. Or to say it differently : in the query you wrote to me, adding the slicing in the WHERE statement changes the behavior of the main query(SELECT [Measures].[VPARCOURS Nombre]...), what if I don't want to change the behavior, just the member value?

Comment: So basically you want to bypass the context of your where clause in your calculation. For that in you calculation add the following . "Dim misc].[CCAMs].[CCAM].defaultmember". Or share the code here and i can adjust it for you.